# Processing: Drawing of ellipses is strange due to antialias

Tags: graphics, processing, antialiasing

The following code produces a somewhat strange output, the ellipses do not look right due to anti-aliasing. What to do?

```
size(500,100);
background(255);
smooth();
fill(0);
for (float i=0;i<10;i+=1.1) ellipse(50+i*40, 50,1+i,1+i*;1.1);
```

Resulting ellipses:

[image: img]

Comment: Are you drawing ellipses or spheres? They looks jagged for spheres, but ellipses may look like that depending on how you draw them. Or are you speaking about the pixels? I'm not sure what is the exact issue when you say "do not look right".

Comment: I do not code in processing but your original `ellipse(50+i&times;40, 50,1+i,1+i&times;1.1);` look fishy like you are overlapping more ellipses ... 2. Cadin edited it into `ellipse(50+i*40, 50,1+i,1+i*;1.1);` which still looks fishy ... what are the parameters of ellipse? why is there `;` inside and `i*` ? Also I would expect GDI style ellipses which are integer ... according to this https://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html it should be 4 operands ...